# React container reusability (with Redux, Immutable and Reselect)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactive-programming, code-reuse

I have use case, where I have a container, say BarChartContainer. This container takes in the URL as a prop, and on the basis of this URL, my saga gets the data required, and sends it to the BarChartComponent (PureComponent), which is called from this BarChartContainer, to render the barchart.
Now, I want this to be dynamic, say if I want to use this in container in 3 places, I just pass in the prop of the URL required and each instance of the container should render the data on the basis of the URL. The problem I am facing is that even though, each call to this container has different props, the container is only having one store. So eventually, only 1 URL is stored in the store (i.e. the the one which came from the props of the third instance of BarChartContainer. How should I configure the store, such that it maintains a tree, to hold the state of the instances.

Here is the code for my container

```
export class BarChartContainer extends React.PureComponent { 
  static propTypes = {
    initializeBarChart: PropTypes.func,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    dataUrl: PropTypes.string,
    addUrlToStore: PropTypes.func,
  };
  /**
   *Defines the default values of certain props
   *
   * @static
   * @memberof BarChartContainer
   */
  static defaultProps = {
    data: {},
    dataUrl: '',
    };
  /**
   *This function is called on the initial load of BarChartContainer
   *
   * @memberof BarChartContainer
   */
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.addUrlToStore(this.props.dataUrl);
    this.props.initializeBarChart();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-barchartcontainer">
        <BarChart data={this.props.data.dataPoints} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  data: selectData(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    initializeBarChart: () => dispatch(defaultAction()),
    addUrlToStore: (url) => dispatch(addUrlToStoreAction(url)),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'barChartContainer', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'barChartContainer`, saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(BarChartContainer);
```

and here is the holder for the three containers

```
    export default class Holder extends React.PureComponent {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container-holder">
            <BarChartContainer dataUrl='url1' />

            <BarChartContainer dataUrl='url2' />

            <BarChartContainer dataUrl='url3' />
          </div>

        );

  }
}
```

Comment: There is a way, but I would re-think the design. You could assign an id to each container and call your selectData with that id or you could convert the container into a PureComponent and move the responsability of selecting that to its parent. IMO the second option would be better.

Comment: Thanks Facundo, but with either of the two cases, I am not achieving what I basically aimed for in the beginning. I want to inject a container, with minimal code change, to a holder, in such a way that the container is configurable in terms of the props I pass, and also the data stored in its store. Could you suggest another technique, such that I am able to maintain a tree like structure to the store. Say, having the parent as the store for barchartcontainer, and then have data associated to each instance of the container created as a child, of the tree ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you want, (IMO) you must re-think the model/process.

Containers which are tied to stores are not reusable, and they should not be, if they represent a different part of the store.In this case as the data is differents sounds to me like they really represent different parts of the store. SO the reusable part would be just the rendering part, but nothing else.

If that is the case, then (IMO) I would create one container for each part of the store I need to represent and I would also create components for rendering the data.

Since each graph would represent semantically different things, having them separately gains in terms of simplicity and scalability.

Another point is, since data comes from different sources, each container will potentially need different ways to handle and manage the communication with its respective source (exceptions, authentication, authorization, etc).

### Option 1:

In your case, I would create, for example, three main containers and one BarChartContainer:

```js
// If this URL is likely going to be hardcoded, then It does not make any sense to be passed as a prop.
// If this URL comes from a dynamic source, then it should have already been injected to the store when the URL was got
const dataUrl = 'http://url.com'; 

class ParticularBussinessBarChart extends React.Component { 
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.addUrlToStore(dataUrl); //This could not make sense
    this.props.initializeParticularBussinessBarChart(); // Why not injecting the url here directly?
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <BarChartContainer dataPoints={this.props.data.dataPoints} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  data: selectData(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    initializeParticularBussinessBarChart: () => dispatch(defaultAction()),
    addUrlToStore: (url) => dispatch(addUrlToStoreAction(url)),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'particularBussinessBarChart', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'particularBussinessBarChart`, saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(ParticularBussinessBarChart);
```

Then I would have a reusable component which would be responsible for rendering the graph, but nothing else.

```js
//This class might become useless with this workaround
export class BarChartContainer extends React.PureComponent { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-barchartcontainer">
        <BarChart data={this.props.dataPoints} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the usage would be:

```js
export default class Holder extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.addUrlToStore(dataUrl); //This could not make sense
    this.props.initializeParticularBussinessBarChart(); // Why not injecting the url here directly?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-holder">
        <ParticularBussinessBarChart/>

        <OtherParticularBussinessBarChart />

        <AnotherParticularBussinessBarChart />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Option 2:

Another option, would be to have a single Holder responsible for fetching and passing the corresponding data to each chart respectively. 
This option would be simpler at the beginning but could become much complex if more charts were added.

```js
export class BarChartContainer extends React.PureComponent { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-barchartcontainer">
        <BarChart data={this.props.dataPoints} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The usage would be:

```js
class Holder extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.initializeBarChart1('url1');
    this.props.initializeBarChart2('url2');
    this.props.initializeBarChart3('url3');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-holder">
        <BarChartContainer dataPoints={this.props.dataPointsChart1} />

        <BarChartContainer dataPoints={this.props.dataPointsChart2} />

        <BarChartContainer dataPoints={this.props.dataPointsChart3} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  dataPointsChart1: selectDataForChar1(),
  dataPointsChart2: selectDataForChar2(),
  dataPointsChart3: selectDataForChar3(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    initializeBarChart1: () => dispatch(correspondingAction()),
    initializeBarChart2: () => dispatch(correspondingAction()),
    initializeBarChart3: () => dispatch(correspondingAction()),
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'holder', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'holder`, saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(ParticularBussinessBarChart);
```

I would prefer taking the first option since It seems to be for me more scalable and simpler. But it really depends on the bussiness and on the nature of the graph you are offering.

Comment: Thanks Facundo, but with either of the two cases, I am not achieving what I basically aimed for in the beginning. I want to inject a container, with minimal code change, to a holder, in such a way that the container is configurable in terms of the props I pass, and also the data stored in its store.   Could you suggest another technique, such that I am able to maintain a tree like structure to the store. Say, having the parent as the store for barchartcontainer, and then have data associated to each instance of the container created as a child, of the tree ?

Comment: Well, I can only think in having a 3rd store, which maintain the basic information you need to share accross containers, so each container will read from two different stores, the common one and the specific one. But the main concept here is that containers should be independent from any other and get everything from the store(s). Do you get the point? I could provide an example of a container reading from two different stores if it was needed.

Comment: Yes, an example of this approach would be great